# Generating upright square lattice with Java

Tags: java, geometry

As part of a personal project, I need to generate an upright square lattice (square of only integer points).

Here is the code:

```
private ArrayList<Point> generateSquare(int area, Point center) {
    int length = (int) Math.rint(Math.sqrt(area));
    Point startingPoint = new Point((int) Math.rint(center.getX() - (length / 2)), (int) Math.rint(center.getY() - (length / 2))); // get bottom left corner
    ArrayList<Point> squarePoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) { // iterate for the length of the square
        squarePoints.add(new Point(startingPoint.x + i, startingPoint.y));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= length - 2; i++) { // iterate for the length of the square minus one since I already have the first row. 2 is subtracted to to account for index 0. This iterates for each row.
        for (int j = 0; j <= length - 1; j++) { // iterates for the points in each row. Index 0 is needed, so length is minus one.
            Point tempPoint = squarePoints.get(i); // gets the point to manipulate
            squarePoints.add(new Point(tempPoint.x, startingPoint.y + j));
        }
    }
    return squarePoints;
}
```

Logically, this is what I am trying to do:

1. I am given the center point of the lattice to be generated. From
   this, I am able to find the bottom left corner. This is stored as
   startingPoint.
2. I then generate the bottom row of points for the square by iterating
   for the length of the square and adding new points to an ArrayList
   called squarePoints.
3. I then iterate again for the length of the square minus one because
   I already have the first row.
4. Within this for loop, I iterate again for the length of the square.
   Here, I get a tempPoint, which is a point from the squarePoints
   ArrayList at the index of the value of the current iteration. The
   reason for doing this is so that I am manipulating the points from
   the original row. I then add a new point that has the same x
   coordinate as the tempPoint and has the y coordinate of
   startingPoint plus the current iteration.

The objective of this process is to add all the remaining rows of the square.

Currently, though, when I run it, it returns an incorrect number of points. I'm hoping that someone else can determine the issue with my code and/or provide a better solution.

Also, since this is a console application, would it be bad practice to use the Point class from AWT in it?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected result ? All integer points within the area of the square ? Or just perimeter points ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will not offer a solution, but suggest a way yo find out what is wrong :

```
private  ArrayList<Point> generateSquare(int area, Point center) {

    ArrayList<Point> squarePoints = new ArrayList<>();
    int length = (int) Math.sqrt(area);
    System.out.println("length = "+length);


    Point startingPoint = new Point((int) Math.rint(center.getX() - (length / 2)), (int) Math.rint(center.getY() - (length / 2))); // get bottom left corner
    System.out.println("startingPoint = "+startingPoint); //is this bottom left ?

    for (int i = 0; i <= (length - 1); i++) { // iterate for the length of the square

        Point point = new Point(startingPoint.x + i, startingPoint.y);
        System.out.println("First loop added "+ point); //does it add what expected ? 
        squarePoints.add(point);
    }

    //.....removed 
    return squarePoints;
}
```

A simpler approach can be: calculate min and max X,Y values, and iterate :

```
  for (int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++) {

       for (int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++) {
           squarePoints.add(new Point(x,y));
       }
  }
```